# Android 12 "Uploaded an APK which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intentfilter, but without 'android : exported'"

Tags: android, android-manifest, intentfilter, android-12

I've a Xamarin Android app and I'm trying to upload a new version on Google Play Console but I receive following error:

"Uploaded an APK which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intentfilter, but without 'android : exported' property set"

Here's my androidManifest.xml file where I can see android:exported property in all tags having intent-filter child.

What's wrong in my androidManifest file or what can I do to solve this issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sg8.jokes" android:versionName="2.2.5" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="39">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:label="Barzaland" android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:allowBackup="true" android:supportsRtl="true" android:name=".MainApplication">
        <meta-data android:name="android.max_aspect" android:value="2.1" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
        <activity android:name="jokes.droid.activities.GeneralActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:launchMode="singleTop"></activity>
        <activity android:name="jokes.droid.activities.ChildActivity" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:exported="false">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
        </provider>
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
        <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="jokes.droid.modules.services.FirebaseFMService" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <permission android:name="${applicationId}.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.droid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml can be extended by used libraries. So if all your activities and services have an exported attribute a library may add further entries without that attribute. Open the APK file e.g. in [Jadx-Gui](https://github.com/skylot/jadx) and check the final AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your answer. Your suggestion helped me to find a service, created by code, without c# correct decoration. I added it ([Service(Exported = true)]) and now new app version passed Google Play pre-check successfully. Thaks for your suggestion